# Getting the lesser n elements of a list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I need to get the lesser n numbers of a list in Python. I need this to be really fast because it's in a critical part for performance and it needs to be repeated a lot of times.

n is usually no greater than 10 and the list usually has around 20000 elements. The list is always different each time I call the function. Sorting can't be made in place.

Initially, I have written this function:

```
def mins(items, n):
    mins = [float('inf')]*n
    for item in items:
        for i, min in enumerate(mins):
            if item < min:
                mins.insert(i, item)
                mins.pop()
                break
    return mins
```

But this function can't beat a simple sorted(items)[:n] which sort the entire list. Here is my test:

```
from random import randint, random
import time

test_data = [randint(10, 50) + random() for i in range(20000)]

init = time.time()
mins = mins(test_data, 8)
print 'mins(items, n):', time.time() - init

init = time.time()
mins = sorted(test_data)[:8]
print 'sorted(items)[:n]:', time.time() - init
```

Results:

```
mins(items, n): 0.0632939338684
sorted(items)[:n]: 0.0231449604034
```

sorted()[:n] is three times faster. I believe this is because:

1. insert() operation is costly because Python lists are not linked lists.
2. sorted() is an optimized c function and mine is pure python.

Is there any way to beat sorted()[:n] ?
Should I use a C extension, or Pyrex or Psyco or something like that?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: There appears to be a canned solution here: [heapq — Heap queue algorithm](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html)

Comment: have tried heapq.nsmallest, but even when is a bit faster that sorted(items)[:n] is not faster than S.Lott's algorithm

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You actually want a sorted sequence of mins.

```
mins = items[:n]
mins.sort()
for i in items[n:]:
    if i < mins[-1]: 
        mins.append(i)
        mins.sort()
        mins= mins[:n]
```

This runs *much* faster because you aren't even looking at mins unless it's provably got a value larger than the given item.  About 1/10th the time of the original algorithm.

This ran in zero time on my Dell.  I had to run it 10 times to get a measurable run time.

```
mins(items, n): 0.297000169754
sorted(items)[:n]: 0.109999895096
mins2(items)[:n]: 0.0309998989105
```

Using `bisect.insort` instead of append and sort may speed this up a hair further.

Comment: A heap would be better; no need to fully sort the whole list for each insert, just a cheaper reheap.

Comment: @erickson: Just edited to add that bisect.insort may have the same effect.

Comment: You're right. using bisect speeds up the algorithm. It's the fastest at the moment. And it's pure python.

Comment: Cool; sorry I don't know python but I figured it would have something along these lines.

Comment: Bisect still isn't optimal. Its worst case is proportional to n * len(items). Try to time it on a strictly decreasing sequence of items. Heap can get that down to O(log(n) * len(items)). Not that there is much difference with such a small n.

Comment: No, bisect is O(log(len(items))). With an strictly decreasing sequence, this algorithm is still faster than heapq.nsmallest(). I just tested

Comment: mins([1, 1, 0, 2], 3) returns [0, 1]. Is it intentional? For example, heapq.nsmallest(3, [1,1,0,2]) returns [0,1,1] i.e., it preserves duplicates and returns exactly n items.

Comment: Duplicate preservation is an easy change.

Comment: @S.Lott: nsmallest_slott_list(3, [0,1,2]) returns [0]. It is wrong. I've posted corrected version of you algorithm.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: nsmallest_slott_list?  Not sure what this code is.  But it looks like you've reversed items and n.  If so, all bets are off.

Comment: s/you/your/ in my previous comment

Comment: @S.Lott: Compare your algorithm and my implementation.

Comment: If the first item is the smallest and n>1 than your algorithm doesn't work.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Thanks for the correction.  Also, you've reversed the arguments from the original question.

Comment: I've used the arguments order from stdlib's heapq.nsmallest(n, items).

Comment: @S.Lott: please update your answer with the corrected version to mark your answer as selected

Answer (score 13):

```
import heapq

nlesser_items = heapq.nsmallest(n, items)
```

Here's a correct version of [S.Lott's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350519/getting-the-lesser-n-elements-of-a-list-in-python#350568):

```
from bisect    import insort
from itertools import islice

def nsmallest_slott_bisect(n, iterable, insort=insort):
    it   = iter(iterable)
    mins = sorted(islice(it, n))
    for el in it:
        if el <= mins[-1]: #NOTE: equal sign is to preserve duplicates
            insort(mins, el)
            mins.pop()

    return mins
```

Performance:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s "import marshal; from nsmallest import nsmallest$label as nsmallest; items = marshal.load(open('items.marshal','rb')); n = 10"\
 "nsmallest(n, items)"
```

```
nsmallest_heapq
100 loops, best of 3: 12.9 msec per loop
nsmallest_slott_list
100 loops, best of 3: 4.37 msec per loop
nsmallest_slott_bisect
100 loops, best of 3: 3.95 msec per loop
```

`nsmallest_slott_bisect` is **3 times faster** than `heapq`'s `nsmallest` (for n=10, len(items)=20000). `nsmallest_slott_list` is only marginally slower. It is unclear why heapq's nsmallest is so slow; its algorithm is almost identical to the presented above (for small n).

Comment: Yes, this is the faster one. Thanks for the corrections. And thanks S.Lott too. This answer is the new chosen one :)

Comment: @Manuel: I think the main credit should go to S.Lott and his answer should be accepted when he corrects his version (it is still incorrect at the time of this comment).

Comment: I agree. I'm going to give him back the selection when he updates the algorithm

Answer (score 2):

A possibility is to use the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) module:

```
import bisect

def mins(items, n):
    mins = [float('inf')]*n
    for item in items:
        bisect.insort(mins, item)
        mins.pop()
    return mins
```

However, it's just a bit faster for me:

```
mins(items, n): 0.0892250537872
sorted(items)[:n]: 0.0990262031555
```

Using psyco does speed it up a bit more:

```
import bisect
import psyco
psyco.full()

def mins(items, n):
    mins = [float('inf')]*n
    for item in items:
        bisect.insort(mins, item)
        mins.pop()
    return mins
```

Result:

```
mins(items, n): 0.0431621074677
sorted(items)[:n]: 0.0859830379486
```

Answer (score 2):

If speed is of utmost concern, the fastest method is going to be with c.
Psyco has an upfront cost, but may prove to be pretty fast.
I would recommend Cython for python -> c compilation (a more up to date for pf Pyrex).

Hand coding it in c would be the best, and allow you to use data structures specific to your problem domain.

But note:

> "Compiling the wrong algorithm in C
>   may not be any faster than the right
>   algorithm in Python" @S.Lott

I wanted to add S.Lott's comment so it gets noticed. Python make an excellent prototype language, where you can iron out an algorithm that you intend to later translate to a lower level language.

Comment: Compiling the wrong algorithm in C may not be any faster than the right algorithm in Python.

Comment: @S.Lott, I absolutely agree :) - Since you had a better algorithm, all I could do was to offer up a language alternative, (plus I wanted to mention Cython, as opposed to Pyrex)

Answer (score 0):

why not just call the select_n_th element in O(N) time and then divide the array into two parts by the n_th element, this should be the fastest one.

ps:
This O(N) algorithm works if you don't specify the order of the n-smallest elements
The link below seems to do the selection algorithm.
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/269554-select-the-nth-smallest-element/

Assuming the array doesn't have duplicate elements, the code works for me. The efficiency still depends on the problem scale, if n<10, probably an O(logn*N) algorithm is enough.

```
import random
import numpy as np
def select(data, n):
    "Find the nth rank ordered element (the least value has rank 0)."
    data = list(data)
    if not 0 <= n < len(data):
        raise ValueError('not enough elements for the given rank')
    while True:
        pivot = random.choice(data)
        pcount = 0
        under, over = [], []
        uappend, oappend = under.append, over.append
        for elem in data:
            if elem < pivot:
                uappend(elem)
            elif elem > pivot:
                oappend(elem)
            else:
                pcount += 1
        if n < len(under):
            data = under
        elif n < len(under) + pcount:
            return pivot
        else:
            data = over
            n -= len(under) + pcount


def n_lesser(data,n):
    data_nth = select(data,n)
    ind = np.where(data<data_nth)
    return data[ind]
```