# How to find the top several values from an array?

Tags: c#, algorithm, arrays, max

I have an array of float values and want the value and more importantly the position of the maximum four values.

I built the system originally to walk through the array and find the max the usual way, by comparing the value at the current position to a recorded max-so-far, and updating a position variable when the max-so-far changes.  This worked well, an O(n) algo that was very simple.  I later learned that I need to keep not only the top value, but the top three or four.  I extended the same procedure and complicated the max-so-far into an array of four max-so-fars and now the code is ugly.

It still works and is still sufficiently fast because only a trivial amount of computations have been added to the procedure.  it still effectively walks across the array and checks each value once.

I do this in MATLAB with a sort function that returns two arrays, the sorted list and the accompanying original position list.  By looking at the first few values I have exactly what I need.  I am replicating this functionality into a C# .NET 2.0 program.

I know that I could do something similar with a List object, and that the List object has a built in sort routine, but I do not believe that it can tell me the original positions, and those are really what I am after.

It has been working well, but now I find myself wanting the fifth max value and see that rewriting the max-so-far checker that is currently an ugly mess of if statements would only compound the ugliness.  It would work fine and be no slower to add a fifth level, but I want to ask the SO community if there is a better way.

Sorting the entire list takes many more computations than my current method, but I don't think it would be a problem, as the list is 'only' one or two thousand floats; so if there is a sort routine that can give back the original positions, that would be ideal.

As background, this array is the result of a Fourier Transform on a kilobyte of wave file, so the max values' positions correspond to the sample data's peak frequencies.  I had been content with the top four, but see a need to really gather the top five or six for more accurate sample classification.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398945/collect-lowest-numbers-algorithm

Comment: Oi, I shouldve searched for the opposite of my question before posting :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can suggest an alternative algorithm which you'll have to code :)

Use a heap of size K where K denotes the count of top elements you want to save. Initialize this to the first K elements of your original array. For all N - K elements walk the array, inserting as and when required.

```
proc top_k (array<n>, heap<k>)
heap <- array<1..k-1>
for each (array<k..n-1>) 
  if array[i] > heap.min
     heap.erase(heap.min)
     heap.insert(array[i])
  end if
end for
```

Comment: +1. Very nice solution requiring only O(nlog k) time and O(k) space.

Answer (score 2):

You could still use your list idea - the elements you put in the list could be a structure which stores both the index and the value; but sorts only on the value, for instance:

```
class IndexAndValue : IComparable<IndexAndValue>
{
    public int index;
    public double value;

    public int CompareTo(IndexAndValue other)
    {
        return value.CompareTo(other.value);
    }
}
```

Then you can stick them in the list, while retaining the information about the index. If you keep only the largest m items in the list, then your efficiency should be O(mn).

Comment: I think you meant "return value.CompareTo(other.value);"

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which algorithm you're currently using, but I'll suggest a simple one.
Admitting that you have an array of floats `f` and a maximum of `capacity`
numbers, you could do the following:

```
int capacity = 4; // number of floats you want to retrieve
float [] f; // your float list
float [] max_so_far = new float[capacity]; // max so far

// say that the first 'capacity' elements are the biggest, for now
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
  max_so_far[i] = i;

// for each number not processed
for (int i = capacity; i < f.length; i++)
{
  // find out the smallest 'max so far' number
  int m = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < capacity; j++)
    if (f[max_so_far[j]] < f[max_so_far[m]])
      m = j;

  // if our current number is bigger than the smallest stored, replace it
  if (f[i] > f[max_so_far[m]])
    max_so_far[m] = i;
}
```

By the end of the algorithm, you'll have the indices of the greatest elements stored
in `max_so_far`.

Do note that if the `capacity` value grows, it will become slightly slower than the
alternative, which is sorting the list while keeping track of the initial positions.
Remember that sorting takes O(n*log n) comparisons, while this algorithm takes O(n*capacity).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use quick-select.
Quick-select returns the position of the k-th element in a list. After you have the position and the value of the k-th element, go over the list and take every element whose value is smaller/larger than the k-th element.

I found a c# implementation of quick-select here: [link text](http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/03/more-ilist-extension-methods.html)

Pros:

1. O(n+k) average running time.

Cons:

1. The k elements found are not sorted. If you sort them the running time is O(n + logk)
2. I haven't checked this, but I think that for a very small k the best option is to do k runs over the array, each time finding the next smallest/largest element.