# Is there a cleaner way to find the highest 5 values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Right now, I'm looping through my whole dictionary five times and keeping the top value after each iteration and deleting the entry. But this seems like a very nasty way to do what I'm trying to do. Essentially I want to get the top 5 greatest value of my dictionary, and return the key, is there a better way to do this rather than iterating through it five times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, by using the [`heapq.nlargest()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
from heapq import nlargest

five_largest = nlargest(5, yourdict, key=yourdict.get)
```

This is more efficient than either looping repeatedly *or* sorting.

The heapq algorithm will do a straight loop over your keys, keep only 5 of them in a heap maintaining the invariant, then when the loop is done return those 5 elements sorted order. The loop is O(N), keeping the loop invariant is O(logK) (where K is the heap size), sorting O(KlogK). Total complexity: O(NlogK)

A sort would need to sort the *full* dictionary, which is O(NlogN). This means the larger N is, the more the `heapq.nlargest()` wins in performance.

Comment: +1 great answer! I have a question - is it correct to state that the heap's size will be 5 in the above code? if so, then `O(N log K)` becomes `O(N log 5)`, which is `O(N)`. Or conversely, if the heap's size is `N` then we're back at `O(N log N)`. Which statement is correct?

Comment: Here K is fixed to 5, yes, but for all Top K comparisons, you need to keep K a variable. And yes, it's also important to keep an eye on K in comparison to N, as K approaches N the `nlargest` approach becomes less attractive. In fact, the `nlargest()` implementation [switches to using `sorted()` when N >= K](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0926adcc335c/Lib/heapq.py#l452).

Comment: For completeness sake: a similar question was asked before and after profiling it was [concluded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/350685/201359) that using `bisect` with a `k`-length list is faster than using `heapq`.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: I'd love to see that retested; both `heapq` and `bisect` have optional C implementations backing up the main algorithms, and there is mention if these were present and in use there. Note that the bisect approach takes no `key` function, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the top 5 values:

```
sorted(mydict.values())[-5:]
```

And to get the corresponding keys:

```
sorted(mydict, key=mydict.get)[-5:]
```

Comment: But he wants the keys, not the values.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I misinterpreted the question, it's fixed now